# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-13268: error obtaining dimension from USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA

Tags: java, spring, oracle11g, oracle-spatial

I'm getting `SQl Exception ORA-13268: error obtaining dimension from USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA`. The query works fine, when I run individually and takes about 3seconds to execute. However I'm getting this error when I run multiple queries for same point using java( I'm using spring-mybatis) from different threads. The thread is created and executed such that for every 3 seconds there are two request going for database.

When I analyzed my java logs first request takes 3 seconds and subsequent request goes on increasing with time taken to execute query as 5,8,12,13,16,17,23,26,29,34,39,.... so on. And finally when the query execution time reaches 100s I'm getting above error. The complete error description is as below.

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-13268: error obtaining dimension from USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MD", line 1723
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MDERR", line 8
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_3GL", line 133

### The error may exist in file [/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/kp/WEB-INF/classes/sqlmap/IKPMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.kp.persistence.IKPMapper.getAddress-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: SELECT  A.BIN_ORDINATE,A.ADDRESS,A.HOUSE_OWNER, A.PIN_CODE FROM KP_GEOM_TBL A WHERE SDO_RELATE(A.BIN_ORDINATE,SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,3857,sdo_point_type(?,?,NULL),NULL,NULL),'mask=TOUCH+CONTAINS')='TRUE'
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-13268: error obtaining dimension from USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MD", line 1723
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MDERR", line 8
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_3GL", line 133

; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [72000]; error code [13268]; ORA-13268: error obtaining dimension from USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MD", line 1723
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MDERR", line 8
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_3GL", line 133
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-13268: error obtaining dimension from USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MD", line 1723
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MDERR", line 8
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_3GL", line 133
```

Initially I was using serialize isolation level. Since my data is not going to change I changed isolation level to read committed (as Oracle supports only these two). Still there was no change in issue.

Here are my DDL

```
 INSERT INTO USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA VALUES
  (
    'KP_GEOM_TBL',
    'BIN_ORDINATE',
    SDO_DIM_ARRAY( SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Longitude', -180, 180, 0.05), 
    SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Latitude', -90, 90, 0.05)    
    ),
    3857 -- SRID for 'Longitude / Latitude (WGS 84)' coordinate system
  );


  CREATE TABLE KP_GEOM_TBL
  (
    BIN_ORDINATE SDO_GEOMETRY NOT NULL ,
    ADDRESS     VARCHAR2(60 BYTE) NOT NULL ,
    HOUSE_OWNER VARCHAR2(60 BYTE) NOT NULL ,
    PIN_CODE      VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL 
  );


  CREATE INDEX KP_GEOM_IDX ON KP_GEOM_TBL (BIN_ORDINATE) INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX PARALLEL;
```

As per the this link [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/10160758) I changed my query as below

```
SELECT /*+ leading(A) use_nl_with_index(A KP_GEOM_IDX) */  A.BIN_ORDINATE,A.ADDRESS,A.HOUSE_OWNER, A.PIN_CODE FROM KP_GEOM_TBL A WHERE SDO_RELATE(A.BIN_ORDINATE,SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,3857,sdo_point_type(?,?,NULL),NULL,NULL),'mask=TOUCH+CONTAINS')='TRUE'
```

Still no luck.

Oracle version: `11.2.0.3.0`

And is 3 second for a spatial query acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Its due to the way table is created. In `create table` I'm using parallel to create the table with degree six. When I disabled it to `no parallel`, the issue I was facing was fixed. Its a bug with oracle version which was fixed in later versions.

```
create table KP_GEOM_TBL parallel(degree 6)
```

Once I executed below statement the issue was fixed and moreover now its taking just couple of mills to query the DB where as previously it was taking few seconds.

```
ALTER TABLE KP_GEOM_TBL NOPARALLEL
```